# Azure DevOpsの単体テストで使用するファイルを相対パス指定したい

Tags: c++, azure, テスト

### 概要

Azure PipelinesのVSTestで実行する単体テストで、テストコード内で指定している相対パスのファイルにアクセスできません
Pipelinesのyamlファイルをどのように編集すれば相対パスでアクセスできるようになりますでしょうか?

### 詳細

Azure DevOpsで画像ファイルを使用した単体テストコードを作成中です
画像ファイルはGit LFSを利用してすでにAzure DevOpsにアップロードしており、Reposの画面から確認することが可能です

テストコードは下記の通りです

```
TEST(OpenCVTest, Empty) {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("..\\..\\images\\sample.bmp");
    bool result = img.empty();
    EXPECT_FALSE(result);
}
```

これをAzure Pipelinesで実行するために作成したyamlファイルの全体は下記の通りです

ローカルのVSで実行するとテストが成功しますが、Azure Pipelinesで実行すると失敗します

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'f39678c2-38da-4e06-831f-137e31f17251'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.exe
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

下記がAzure Pipelinesで確認できるログです

```
X OpenCVTest.Empty [1ms]
  Error Message:
Value of: result
  Actual: true
Expected: false
  Stack Trace:
  at test.cpp:14 in D:\a\1\s\Sample-Test1\test.cpp:line 14
```

### 試したこと

#### テストコード中に画像のサイズを出力する処理を挿入する

自作のOpenCVNuGetパッケージが適切に呼ばれていない可能性を考慮して下記のテストコードを作成しました

```
TEST(OpenCVTest, Empty) {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("..\\..\\images\\sample.bmp");
    bool result = img.empty();
    std::cout<<img.size()<<std::endl;
    EXPECT_FALSE(result);
}
```

ローカル環境上での結果は下記の通りでした

```
[----------] 1 test from OpenCVTest
[ RUN      ] OpenCVTest.Empty
[1280 x 640]
[       OK ] OpenCVTest.Empty (18 ms)
[----------] 1 test from OpenCVTest (24 ms total)
```

Azure Pipelines上での結果は下記のとおりでした

```
X OpenCVTest.Empty [1ms]
  Error Message:
   [0 x 0]
Value of: result
  Actual: true
Expected: false
```

このことからOpenCVのメソッドは適切に呼ばれていると判断しました

#### searchFolderにより深いフォルダを指定してみる

[参考サイト](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374440/azure-devops-pipeline-test-step-fails-incorrect-path-to-data-files)にパスの指定方法に関する記述がありましたので、絶対パスで指定しました

```
- task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*test*.exe
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(buildPlatform)\$(buildConfiguration)'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

テストが実行されませんでした
その時のログは下記の通りです

```
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in D:\a\1\s\x64\Release\Sample-Test1.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
Results File: D:\a\_temp\TestResults\VssAdministrator_WIN-DVJJ2EGUBGP_2020-06-13_12_12_52.trx
```

#### フォルダの階層をAzure Pipelines上で表示してみる

dirコマンドを相対パスで使用して正しいフォルダが指定できているかどうか確認しました

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(buildPlatform)\$(buildConfiguration)\..\..\'
```

結果は下記の通りで、画像を保存しているフォルダが表示されていることを確認できました

```
06/13/2020  11:50 AM    <DIR>          .
06/13/2020  11:50 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/13/2020  11:50 AM             2,623 .gitattributes
06/13/2020  11:50 AM             6,084 .gitignore
06/13/2020  11:50 AM             1,221 azure-pipelines.yml
06/13/2020  11:50 AM                68 header.cpp
06/13/2020  11:50 AM               121 header.h
06/13/2020  11:50 AM    <DIR>          images ← 画像フォルダ
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました
[こちらのサイト](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788144/how-to-use-git-lfs-with-azure-repos-and-pipelines)に類似した質問があり、yamlにgit lfsを有効にする処理が必要でした

最終的に完成したyamlファイルは以下の通りです

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

# ここから
steps:
- checkout: self
  lfs: true
# ここまでを追加

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'f39678c2-38da-4e06-831f-137e31f17251'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.exe
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```